# How to display a gallery and text with fancybox?

Tags: fancybox

I'd like to create a fancybox with a gallery of images on the left side, and some text on the right side of the box. Is it possible to do so? By gallery, I refer to the gallery example given on the fancybox website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider my fancybox "*a la*" facebook script.

You can see it [working here](http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxALAfacebook_26Mar12.html).

It requires [fancybox v2.x](http://fancyapps.com).