# I want to add multiple "side divs" with text to fancybox

Tags: fancybox

I'm trying to add a side rectangular div to fancybox that would float to the left of the image (same height), and have multiple placed text fields(h1's and p's), if that makes sense?

I searched around on stack overflow and couldn't find a similar question.  If you know of a thread point me there!

Comment: Create a div with the html laid out as you describe above and then call fancybox on it to make it appear as a model dialog.

Comment: Thankyou for answering! Ok, so lay out the normal html and then "call" fancybox?  This may sound stupid, but how do I do that? And, I'm not sure what a model dialog is.

Comment: Some time ago I created "fancybox a la facebook" but it only works with fancybox up to v2.0.6 ... I haven't had the time to update it to v2.1.x ... you may want to check it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10049299/1055987

Comment: sorry the model dialog should be modal dialog. But have a look at the fancybox page. Essentially what you do is a create a div with your html layout, give it id popup or whatever. Then in you javascript do something like $(document).ready(function(){$('#popup).fancybox(/*optional parameters here*/)});